# How to replace method calls in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, regexp-replace

We are replacing Redux with useContext, so `dispatch()` method need to be replaced with `auth.` how?

We have this:

```js
dispatch(
  updateClientAndServer({
    keyPath: [organizationShortId, 'posts', postId, 'text'],
    value: v,
    operation: 'setValue',
  })
)
```

and would have this:

```js
auth.updateClientAndServer({
  keyPath: [organizationShortId, 'posts', postId, 'text'],
  value: v,
  operation: 'setValue',
})
```

Is it possible make a find and replace like this?

The challenge is the closing bracket. :) I hope I do not have to replace them manually. Of course the content, the object can be arbitrary.

Comment: that can't be done with regex, you need to write a script that searches the start location, do bracket matching/counting to find the end of the block, and then replace the stuff

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can simply replace the entire code with **find and replace**;
copy and paste the entire *dispatch* block in **find** and the *auth* block in **replace**